# How does RCS compare to extending text message protocol?

Tags: communication-protocols, protocols

Text message constantly keeps adding more emoji so I know the protocol could be extended with a delimiter at minimum.

How does RCS compare to extending text message protocol? I ask this because I somehow doubt Apple will adopt the new standard but could be wrong when it doesn't support encryption.

[Here is a list of feature comparisons to iMessage](https://www.cnet.com/news/imessage-vs-googles-new-texting-update-can-androids-messaging-app-take-on-apple/)

Comment: @D.W. do you have a better site recommendation?  I tried simplifying the question a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your edits, but I'm still unclear on what exactly you are asking. Perhaps I don't understand what kind of comparison you're looking for and what specifically you want to know beyond what's already in the link you shared, or what specifically you have in mind by "extending text message protocol".  Perhaps it would help to share what research you've done.  Given that these appear to be commercial products, it's not clear to me whether the question will be judged on-topic here.  This doesn't seem like a question about computer science to me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Communication_Services, https://www.gsma.com/futurenetworks/rcs/

Comment: Seems off-topic here, unfortunately.